# Are Diablo 2 Act II mercenaries affected by weapon reach?

Tags: diablo-ii

Act II mercenaries are capable of only using polearms, spears, and javelins.  Polearms are the obvious choice due to the number of good runewords that can be made (particularly Insight and Infinity).  [The Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/elite/polearms.shtml) lists stats for the rangeadder (the weapon-related portion of the melee reach calculation) of each elite polearm (with similar stats for lower-difficulty polearms).

Are Act II mercenaries affected by the weapon reach?  Against the same size monster, will my Act II mercenary have a smaller reach with a `Scythe` or `Thresher` than with a `Poleaxe` or `Great Poleaxe`?

Comment: The reason why you would want to pick a particular type of weapon is for the type of runeword you can stick into it and its attack speed.  I don't think reach is that big of a factor.  In the end, I suspect the answer is yes they are affected by reach, but I can't confirm and its not that important anyway.

Comment: Availability is actually fairly crucial as well, as you'll want both a low-level insight and an eth endgame insight. Ogre axes and CVs can't have more than 4 sockets, but the rest can. IAS makes a big difference of course, but it depends on which runeword - Infinity you've got Crushing Blow, Insight you don't. In the end I'm just curious - "which ethereal elite polearm should I make my infinity out of" isn't exactly my question, though it's not a bad one given the complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything I can find suggests that the Rangeadder stat is not used by mercenaries.  They have fixed range of 3.

[Source](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=649565)

[Source](http://www.diablopodcast.com/forums/showthread.php?t=533799)

Comment: interesting....